# Cookies is not saving when page cache is enable for magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am saving cookies in controller by getting post data to from custom form.
Issues is cookies is not saving when page cache is enable.

```
$this->_cookieManager->setPublicCookie(
                         self::year,
                         $year,
                         $metadata
                    );
```

This is a controller where code is written.

Anyone have a solution? 
Page cache creating a issues for me.
Advanced Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Try following code:**

```
public function setCustomCookie($value, $duration = 86400)
{
    $metadata = $this->_cookieMetadataFactory
        ->setDuration($duration)
        ->setPath($this->_sessionManager->getCookiePath())
        ->setDomain($this->_sessionManager->getCookieDomain())
        ->setHttpOnly($httpOnly); //true OR false

    $this->_cookieManager->setPublicCookie(
        self::COOKIE_NAME,
        $value,
        $metadata
    );
}

public function getCustomCookie()
{
      return $this->_cookieManager->getCookie(self::COOKIE_NAME);
}
```